# How would I go about using a text-box to complete a URL and then open said URL in a new tab?

Tags: html

I'm looking to make a simple HTML site that redirects to another URL. I want the input inside the textbox to 'complete' a URL, and then open said completed URL. However I've not found any way to do such a thing, and I'm rather new to coding in general so I turned to here in the last attempt.

I want the user to be able to input something (say they input "abcxyz"), and when they click a button or press enter, they are redirected to something like 'genericsite.com/[input]' (in this case, genericsite.com/abcxyz).

I assume I'll have to use some JS for this, but I have almost zero knowledge on JS so I was having trouble finding any topic on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include a piece of code that you've tried for achieving your goal. You can always follow tutorials for HTML/JS from websites like w3shcools.com etc.

Comment: You would indeed use JavaScript for this.  But from the terminology you're using it sounds like you may be searching the wrong terms.  Don't look for a ready-made solution for *exactly* what you want to do.  Instead, look for each individual component of your logic.  The general things you want to do are: (1) Handle a button click.  (2) Get a value from a text input.  (3) Concatenate strings.  (4) Redirect to a URL (in a new tab).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding an old snippet of code from a few years back that worked for me

```
{
    var name = document.getElementById('myName').value;
    var url = 'http://www.genericsite.com/' + encodeURIComponent(name);

    // In current window
    window.location.href = url;

    // In new window
    window.open(url);
}
```